# What is "grpc.Call" in node.js

Tags: node.js, grpc

I'm a node.js programmer, and is using module [grpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc).

And when I read the source codes of `./node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/**/*.js`, I found a definition which is frequently used: `grpc.Call`.

See `server.js`:

```
/**
 * Handle an error on a call by sending it as a status
 * @access private
 * @param {grpc.Call} call The call to send the error on
 * @param {Object} error The error object
 */
function handleError(call, error) {
```

And when I print it in console, like:
`console.log(require('./node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/grpc_extension.js').Call.toString());`

The result is:
`// function Call() { [native code] }`

That means the real source code of type `grpc.Call` is not in JavaScript. My question is where can I find the definition of this type, or source code of this type.

It would be good to understand the type definition of `grpc.Call` to help reading the source code of grpc node.js.

Comment: Looks like source is https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/node/ext/call.cc#L510 here

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Yes, it's just what i'm looking for. Thank you.